# How to find CEO's to interview for B2B product research?

Tags: user-research, interview

I'm the sole UX guy with a local startup on a B2B product in the business intelligence space.

The problem is though: our product is geared more towards CEO and C-level types - not the people you can just send a cold email to and expect to get a response.

Any tips on good methods for getting good, in depth user interviews with these types of customers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Find them and ask them.** Be sincere, and interesting. Pick specific people, study them, and have specific reasons you want to talk to them. Write a short, coherent letter and if your motives are compelling you may get a few bites. Don't be stupid and sabotage yourself by sending a boilerplate research recruitment letter to Warren Buffett or someone.

**Recruiting is always hard.** Even when I do AdWords or something, I still have to harass my survey respondents for weeks to get the interviews lined up. And even then, it's rarely more than 50-80% who show up for their scheduled, paid interview.

Also - C-suite folks generally don't mess around. Be prepared to make good use of their time or they'll be bored in 15 seconds and probably bail on the interview. You better [know what you're doing](https://i2.wp.com/blog.handrailux.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/HR_Interview_DoDont_Infographic.png) as an interviewer.